# Check null values in data fetched from SQL database

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pyodbc

I want to store the data in numpy arrays fetched from the database. I want to make sure that no null value (None) go to the numpy array(throws an error anyway doing that). I have tried to do it the following way but it does not work. For some reason, NullValueCheck() always returns true How can I know about null values and do something about it?

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc as odbc

cnxn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID, BuildingID, Title FROM Something"""")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
cnxn.close()

ID = [i[0] for i in rows]
buildingID = [i[1] for i in rows]
title = [i[2] for i in rows]

def NullValueCheck(rows):
     if (any(elem is None for elem in rows[0])):
         return True
     else:
         return False

if NullValueCheck(rows):
    ID_array = np.fromiter(ID, dtype= np.int32)
```

**Edit:**
It turns out that I don't have to write all that code. I can achieve the same using pandas dataframe that I want to achieve from numpy array.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc

cnxn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql("""SELECT ID, BuildingID, Title FROM Something""", cnxn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this is easiest to address in your source SQL. `COALESCE` is helpful here:

```
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql("""SELECT ID, COALESCE(BuildingID, 0) AS BuildingID, Title FROM Something""", cnxn)
```

This will return `0` if the value of `BuildingID` is NULL. Different SQL databases have functions for specific NULL checking (`ISNULL` in SQL Server, `IFNULL` in MySQL, for example), but `COALESCE` is the most cross database compatible.